# How did Chewbacca end up on the planet Mimban?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, at the planet Mimban, Han gets thrown into a pit where he was supposed to get eaten by a beast tied in chains, who turns out to be Chewbacca.

In *Revenge of the Sith*, Chewbacca was shown at Kashyyyk when Yoda leaves.

However, **how did Chewbacca end up on the planet Mimban?** This isn't explained in the movie, but **is there any in or out-of-universe explanation for it?**

Comment: There is a 9 year gap between revenge of the sith (19 BBY), and solo (13-10 BBY). I'm guessing Chewbacca did plenty in that decade.

Comment: @CyberClaw Of course, he did plenty during that decade, but I am interested in knowing how he ended up on that planet.

Comment: During the movie, didn't they mention that the wookies were captured fleeing Kashyyyk? Hence why Chewie is searching and trying to free his people?

Comment: There will probably be a Chewie spin-off movie after the Boba Fett flick.  It will explain all this.

Comment: From what I understand, there is now a plan for a Mandalorian TV series on Disney's upcoming streaming service (Disney+).  Sadly, no further plans for a Boba Fett, Chewie, nor any other Star Wars Story spin-off movie are in the works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca) also expands on the previous answer:

> Following the reorganization of the Republic into the Galactic Empire,
>   Chewbacca saw his people sent to work as slaves, or as miners in
>   places such as Kessel, or made to serve as science
>   experiments. **At some point, Chewbacca and several other Wookiees
>   were captured and enslaved by several Trandoshan slavers.** Like
>   them, he was forced into slavery, working to cut the wroshyr trees in
>   order to feed the Imperial Army. **Chewbacca attempted to escape but
>   was betrayed by a greedy Kowakian monkey-lizard bounty hunter
>   and turned over as a Imperial prisoner and was sent to the Imperial
>   planet Kethmandi. There he had the opportunity to escape captivity,
>   but sacrificed his own freedom to save a fellow prisoner. During
>   as a prisoner for the Galactic Empire, he was later sent to the
>   Imperial Army on Mimban.** Whilst on Mimban, he came to be referred to
>   as "the Beast". Chewbacca also learned that the Imperials were
>   trying to sell him off as a pit fighter.

Wookiepedia

Answer (score 2):

There is some information in *Solo: The Official Guide*:

> "The Beast":
>
> **Betrayal by a greedy bounty hunter has landed Chewbacca in Imperial custody on Mimban.** The local Imperial officers there have neither the resources nor the inclination to process the prisoner and send him back to Kashyyyk. Instead, they keep the filthy, famished Wookiee shackled in a mud-filled pen.